# Access build folder in Xcode Server CI bot run (env variables?)

Tags: xcode, continuous-integration, xcode6, xcode-bots

I need to access the folder that is created dynamically during each bot integration. On one of the run it is something like this -

> /Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/*a3c682dd0c4d569a3bc84e58eab88a48*/DerivedData/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/my.app

I would like to get to this folder in an post trigger, how do I go about it? Based on the wwdc talk it seems like some environment variables like 'XCS_INTEGRATION_RESULT' and XCS_ERROR_COUNT etc.. are being used. Also I can see in logs something like PROJECT_DIR.

But I can't access any of these variables from my command line(is it because I am a different user than the bot?) 
Also where can I find the list of variables created by this CI system?

Answer (score 25):

I have been echoing set to the bot log, the first line of my bot script is simply

```
set
```

When you view the log after the integration is complete it will be in your trigger output.

```
XCS_ANALYZER_WARNING_CHANGE=0
XCS_ANALYZER_WARNING_COUNT=0
XCS_ARCHIVE=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-76eb5292bd7eff1bfe4160670c2d4576/Archive.xcarchive
XCS_BOT_ID=4f7c7e65532389e2a741d29758466c18
XCS_BOT_NAME='Reader'
XCS_BOT_TINY_ID=00B0A7D
XCS_ERROR_CHANGE=0
XCS_ERROR_COUNT=0
XCS_INTEGRATION_ID=76eb5292bd7eff1bfe4160670c2d4576
XCS_INTEGRATION_NUMBER=15
XCS_INTEGRATION_RESULT=warnings
XCS_INTEGRATION_TINY_ID=FF39BC2
XCS_OUTPUT_DIR=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Integration-76eb5292bd7eff1bfe4160670c2d4576
XCS_PRODUCT='Reader.ipa'
XCS_SOURCE_DIR=/Library/Developer/XcodeServer/Integrations/Caches/4f7c7e65532389e2a741d29758466c18/Source
XCS_TESTS_CHANGE=0
XCS_TESTS_COUNT=0
XCS_TEST_FAILURE_CHANGE=0
XCS_TEST_FAILURE_COUNT=0
XCS_WARNING_CHANGE=36
XCS_WARNING_COUNT=36
```

Comment: Although it seems obvious, this answer was extremely helpful and put me on the right path when I had a similar issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

@Viktor is correct, these variables only exist during their respective sessions. @Pappy gave a great list of those variables.

They can be used in a script like so:

```
IPA_PATH="${XCS_OUTPUT_DIR}/${XCS_BOT_NAME}.ipa"
echo $IPA_PATH
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not familiar with Xcode Server but generally Unix/CI systems when export environment variables they only export it to the current session.

If you want to set an environment variable persistently you have to set it in an initializer file like ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bashrc so it always gets set/loaded when a shell session starts (ex: when you log in with Terminal - the exact file depends on what kind of shell you start).

It wouldn't make much sense to export these persistently either, because in that case if you run different integrations these would simply overwrite each others exported environment variables (they would set the same environment variables).

That's why the systems which communicate through environment variables *usually don't write the variables into persistent* initialiser file rather just [export](http://ss64.com/bash/export.html) the variables. With **export** the variable is *accessible from the process which exports it and from the child processes the process starts*.

For example in a bash script if you **export** a variable you can access it from the bash script after the export and from any command/program you start from the bash script, but when the bash script finishes the environment won't be accessible anymore.

**edit**
Just to clarify it a bit: You should be able to access these environment variables from a post trigger script, run by Xcode Server but you most likely won't be able to access these from your Terminal/command line.

> Also where can I find the list of variables created by this CI system?

You can print all the available environment variables with the [env](http://ss64.com/bash/env.html) command. In a bash script simply type **env** in a new line like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
env
```

This will print all the available environment variables (not just the ones defined by Xcode Server!) - you can simply pipe it to a file for inspection if you want to, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
env > $HOME/envinspect.txt
```

After this script runs you can simply open the envinspect.txt file in the user's home folder.