# Xcode CI and cocoapods private repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git, continuous-integration, cocoapods

I've been trying to setup OSX server to use Xcode CI. My project uses cocoapods and a private repo. I've been following this tutorial: http://papaanton.com/setting-up-xcode-6-and-apple-server-4-0-for-continues-integration-with-cocoapods/

But when I login as the _xcsbuildd user and run the command to add the private repo I get the following error message

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir '<repo name>': permission denied
```

I don't have much experience with users and command line tools. I've seen many comments online saying people need to change permissions to get it to work. But I have no idea what I need to change and where.

Can anyone tell me where / what / how I need to modify to give this user access to complete this process.

Answer (score 1):

Just found the answer. Had no idea where cocoapods was storing these repos. I opened finder. Cmd + shift + g

typed in `~/.cocoapods/repos`

right click on the repos folder and give "everyone" read & write access to the folder. All good now, CI working completely