# How to get SHA of commit for Xcode Bot "Run Script" Trigger? Updating status of tests on Github

Tags: xcode, git, continuous-integration, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I have created an Xcode Bot that integrates on each commit.

In the "Run Script" Trigger I would like to update the current GitHub commit with the integration status of Tests that were run. Pretty standard CI stuff.

[image: Xcode Bot Run Script]

I'll then be running a script like the below:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-type: application/json"
-H 'Authorization: token TOKEN_HERE' -d 
'{
"state": "success",
"target_url": "https://example.com/build/status",
"description": "The build succeeded!",
"context": "continuous-integration/jenkins"
}' 
https://api.github.com/repos/ORGANIZATION_HERE/REPO_HERE/statuses/SHA_HERE
```

It looks like I'll be able to get the `success` or `failure` states from the Xcode Bot Environment variables:

[Access build folder in Xcode Server CI bot run (env variables?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25127146/access-build-folder-in-xcode-server-ci-bot-run-env-varaibles)

However, the SHA of the current commit is not listed. How am I able to get the SHA of the commit used for the Integration at this point, to be used in the GitHub Status API request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`XCS_OUTPUT_DIR` has a file called `sourceControl.log`.  This file has logs like the following:

```
"DVTSourceControlLocationRevisionKey" : "3787c0d9e5107861a8b8d4c7300b2d414ad41dbb",
```

You can parse that log to find the SHA.

Perhaps more practically, [CaveJohnson](https://github.com/drewcrawford/CaveJohnson) can pull the SHA:

```
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:$PATH
SHA=`cavejohnson getSha`
```

Or it can just go ahead and set the GitHub status as a one-liner:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:$PATH
cavejohnson setGithubStatus
```

Notably, there are more statuses than just success and failure, there are at least 6 that I'm aware of.  You can read more about them in my [Xcode 6 CI Missing Manual](http://faq.sealedabstract.com/xcodeCI/#figuring-out-build-status).

Answer (score 3):

I am using this code in my Xcode Bot triggers to get the SHA of the commit:

```
git -C ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/name_of_your_git_repo rev-parse HEAD
```

And this to get the branch name:

```
git -C ${XCS_SOURCE_DIR}/name_of_your_git_repo rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

This executes a git command in the source directory, replace "name_of_your_git_repo" by the name of your repository on git

Comment: ${XCS_PRIMARY_REPO_DIR} is also available.  See XCS environment variables — https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/xcode_guide-continuous_integration/EnvironmentVariableReference.html

Answer (score 1):

Using the `cavejohnson` code in the other answer, which gets the hash from certain keys an Xcode log, I ran into an issue where [the returned hash was an outdated one from the last build](https://github.com/drewcrawford/CaveJohnson/issues/6).

I'm now instead using `git rev-parse HEAD` to get the hash of the commit that was actually used in the CI build. I've submitted this as a revision to `cavejohnson`.

Use `get_sha()` to retrieve the SHA-1 hash:

```
def get_sha():
    return get_repo_sha(get_git_directory())

def get_git_directory():
    for subdir in os.listdir('.'):
        if is_git_directory(subdir):
            return subdir
    assert False

def is_git_directory(path = '.'):
    return subprocess.call(['git', '-C', path, 'status'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')) == 0    

def get_repo_sha(repo):
    sha = subprocess.check_output(['git', 'rev-parse', 'HEAD'], cwd=repo).decode('ascii').strip()
    return sha
```